# re-injection of captured packets results in incorrect ethernet checksum

Tags: python, network-programming, scapy

When playing with scapy I observed the following behavior. The scapy manual page suggests as an example something like

```
a=sniff(filter="tcp port 110")
...
sendp(a)
```

to re-inject captured packets. However, when I tried this myself, wireshark tells me *ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE INCORRECT* on all re-injected packets. (It does not matter which packets I capture and re-inject.) When I examined the packets interactively with scapy, I noticed that the Ethernet trailer (and the checksum) is not displayed. Moreover, there is no method to modify or set the trailer.

Apparently, scapy does not work as I expect - what am I missing? How can I re-inject a copy of an ethernet frame such that it appears as valid?

#### Detailed Example

For this example I consider an ARP packet. However, the issue is present with other packet types as well.

This is what wireshark recorded (dumped by `tcpdump -v -XX -r ...`):

```
14:05:39.517932 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.141.150 tell 192.168.140.193, length 46
    0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 90b1 1c47 c81e 0806 0001  .........G......
    0x0010:  0800 0604 0001 90b1 1c47 c81e c0a8 8cc1  .........G......
    0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 c0a8 8d96 0000 0000 0000  ................
    0x0030:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000            ............
```

This is how scapy3 saw it:

```
>>> x = sniff(count=1, filter='arp')
>>> bytes(x[0])
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x90\xb1\x1cG\xc8\x1e\x08\x06\x00\x01\x08\x00\x06\x04\x00\x01\x90\xb1\x1cG\xc8\x1e\xc0\xa8\x8c\xc1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xa8\x8d\x96\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> x[0].show()
###[ Ethernet ]### 
  dst= ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  src= 90:b1:1c:47:c8:1e
  type= ARP
###[ ARP ]### 
     hwtype= 0x1
     ptype= 0x800
     hwlen= 6
     plen= 4
     op= who-has
     hwsrc= 90:b1:1c:47:c8:1e
     psrc= 192.168.140.193
     hwdst= 00:00:00:00:00:00
     pdst= 192.168.141.150
###[ Padding ]### 
        load= '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

And then...

```
>>> sendp(x[0])
.
Sent 1 packets.
```

This is what wireshark captured

```
14:14:44.901556 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.141.150 tell 192.168.140.193, length 60
    0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 90b1 1c47 c81e 0806 0001  .........G......
    0x0010:  0800 0604 0001 90b1 1c47 c81e c0a8 8cc1  .........G......
    0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 c0a8 8d96 0000 0000 0000  ................
    0x0030:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 3203 3136  ............2.16
    0x0040:  3803 3139 3207 696e 2d61                 8.192.in-a
```

As you see, the last 14 bytes are quite odd. In fact, regular ARP packets have length 46 and not 60. (Wireshark shows it as having length 74, see image below).

[image: Wireshark's view]

#### strace

This is what `strace` saw on capture (note: this is a different packet than in the example above)

```
2552  recvfrom(12, "\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x50\x56\xbf\x0c\x83\x08\x06\x00\x01\x08\x00\x06\x04\x00\x01\x00\x50\x56\xbf\x0c\x83\xc0\xa8\x8d\xb0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xa8\x8e\x6b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00", 65535, 0, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, sa_data="\x08\x06\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x06\x00\x50\x56\xbf\x0c\x83"}, [20->18]) = 60
```

And this is what `strace` saw on resending (matching the preceding capture)

```
2552  sendto(12, "\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x50\x56\xbf\x0c\x83\x08\x06\x00\x01\x08\x00\x06\x04\x00\x01\x00\x50\x56\xbf\x0c\x83\xc0\xa8\x8d\xb0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xa8\x8e\x6b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00", 60, 0, NULL, 0) = 60
```

#### System Information

Just in case that his matters: The platform is Kali Linux (4.16.0-kali2-amd64), regularly kept up-to-date and not meddled with. The OS is running in a Virtualbox VM (Virtualbox 5.2.12). The other platform where I tried this is a DELL PC with Kali Linux (no VM).

#### Insight so far

An ethernet frame has to contain at least 64 bytes, including 14 bytes header and 4 bytes of FCS, so the payload has to have at least 46 bytes (Wireshark usually shows the header but not the FCS, this is why Wireshark shows an ARP packet to have 60 bytes instead of 64). An ARP packet (for Ethernet/IPv4) has 28 bytes. This leaves 18 bytes of padding. For some reason yet unknown to me if I send 60 bytes (not including the FCS) raw via `sendto()`, something (the driver?) appends another 14 bytes, messing up the FCS.

Below is the dump (for yet another packet) of `strace -x -s 1000 -e trace=%network -p ...` that I get when I invoke `sendp(pkt)` in scapy:

```
socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, 768)        = 12
setsockopt(12, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [0], 4) = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 13
setsockopt(12, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, {mr_ifindex=if_nametoindex("eth0"), mr_type=PACKET_MR_PROMISC, mr_alen=0, mr_address=}, 16) = 0
bind(12, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, sll_protocol=htons(ETH_P_ALL), sll_ifindex=if_nametoindex("eth0"), sll_hatype=ARPHRD_NETROM, sll_pkttype=PACKET_HOST, sll_halen=0}, 20) = 0
setsockopt(12, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [1073741824], 4) = 0
setsockopt(12, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [1073741824], 4) = 0
getsockname(12, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, sa_data="\x00\x03\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x06\x08\x00\x27\xbc\xeb\x8a"}, [20->18]) = 0
sendto(12, "\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x50\x56\xbf\x0c\x83\x08\x06\x00\x01\x08\x00\x06\x04\x00\x01\x00\x50\x56\xbf\x0c\x83\xc0\xa8\x8d\xb0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xa8\x8e\x6b\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff", 60, 0, NULL, 0) = 60
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 11
setsockopt(12, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_DROP_MEMBERSHIP, {mr_ifindex=if_nametoindex("eth0"), mr_type=PACKET_MR_PROMISC, mr_alen=0, mr_address=}, 16) = 0
```

Comment: Could you edit your post, and share with us a random packet that scapy has sniffed (both its raw data and its fancy print): `bytes(a[0])` `a[0].show()`. so that we can see how the FCS are computed

Comment: Thank you for your interest. See the updated version.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One last thing: could you re-try using scapy installed via `pip install scapy>=2.4.0` or github, as not yet available on Debian). Scapy3 is outdated and deprecated.

Comment: I see, so I tossed kamene and scapy3. Unfortunately, scapy - installed as you advised - shows still the same behavior.

Comment: Good, I will investigate

Comment: I can't replicate :/ When I sniff packets (last dev version) and send them back, Wireshark detects them as correctly built :/ Could you try to call `pkt[ARP].remove_payload()` before sending the packet back, just to remove the extra padding ?

Comment: @Cukic0d: Indeed, the payload seems to make the trouble. If I remove it or if I trim it down to four bytes (so that the resulting packet is 60 bytes long) then wireshark seems to be happy.

Comment: Well the problem might be comming from how your driver appends the FCS (as scapy does not append any). You should try removing the padding (full of \x00) before sending the packet. You can use `pkt[ARP].remove_payload()`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using wireshark to capture the outgoing packets on the box that's generating them and those outgoing packets are the ones you see with incorrect frame check sequences (FCS). That's because, in sending, the network adapter actually *calculates* and appends the FCS as it's transmitting the frame, but the copy of the frame given to wireshark happens from the in-memory version before it's transferred to the network adapter. (This is true with pretty much all modern NICs: the checksum is calculated in the adapter because it can use a hardware CRC generator that is *way* faster than software can do it.)

So, even though you may be re-transmitting a previously received frame without modification, its original FCS was dropped along the way, and a new FCS will be generated on the way out, but on the transmitting box, you can't see that, so wireshark is looking at whatever data (likely all-zeroes) is in that location within the frame in the buffer it got from `libpcap`.

I'm betting if you capture these same packets at another station on the LAN (for example at the destination), you'll find that, on the wire, they actually do have the correct checksum.

By the way, there are a couple of settings in the Ethernet protocol preferences pane in wireshark that control how this is handled/reported.

Comment: Funny, though, that kamene (the successor of scapy3) doesn't show this behavior. Moreover, the frames that I replay with scapy are longer than the ones that I record.

Comment: Meh kamene is more than buggy and outdated. It’s based on a 2015 version of scapy, and is missing around 3000 commits